# Li ion battery polarity

Tags: battery-charging, polarity

For a Li ion battery showing 0 volts, should the negative connector from the charger go to the pin with 444,000 ohms or 362,000 ohms relative to common lead from a multimeter that was in contact with the other pin. I don't have physical access to the battery since it's in a sealed device. Do the resistance measurements suggest anything about polarity?

Comment: If it is showing 0V it isn't dead; It is damaged and should not be charged. Li-ions show 3V when dead, 4.2V when full. It's not like a gas tank that reads 0mL when empty.

Comment: That said, your statements about resistance are incoherent so you might not even be measuring the voltage properly.

Comment: Listen to @DKNguyen . Never try to charge it! If you open the cap (+ side) you will find a circuitry. You can defeat it, charge it, and may see it explode.

Comment: Neither : it should be recycled.

Comment: @DKNguyen In general I agree with you but from personal experience, I have raised several Panasonic cells from 0.00 V to working at full capacity and minimal self-discharge.

Comment: Sealed device? Sounds like the BMS has tripped. If you knew what you where doing you would break it open and measure directly on the cell(s).

Comment: @QWERTY resistance measurements measure resistance and polarity can't be inferred from them. Use the meter in DC voltage mode to determine polarity

Answer (score 4):

The Li-ion battery protection circuit has detected that the battery has dropped below its minimum safe voltage and disconnected its terminals, preventing further discharge. That’s why it shows 0V on its terminals. Internally it might be some voltage below, say, 2.5V, but you won’t see this unless you take apart the battery.

More about this protection here: https://www.digikey.com/en/maker/blogs/lithium-ion-cell-protection

The battery cannot be discharged anymore in this state. It might be able to be charged and made operational again provided you have an appropriate charger, or you know what you're doing using a power supply.

And here's the trouble. The nature of your question leads me (and others in the comments) to believe that you could be attempting something unsafe.

If it isn't obvious to you which are the (+) and (-) terminals on the battery and your proposed charger, *and the charger isn't designed for the battery you're using*, **don't try to charge it**. The battery could be damaged, or worse, explode and catch fire.